# trigger canActivate every 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

I am currently using a canActivate-service for my angular parent route and therefore for all the childroutes. looks like that for example

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
canActivate: [ServiceWhichShouldRunEvery10Minutes],
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
children: [
  {
    path: routeA,
    component: a,
  },
  {
    path: routeB,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: b,
  },...
```

canActivate-method

```
  async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
// condition that i want to check every 10 minutes
}
```

How do I ensure, that this canActivate service will be fired every 10 minutes?
Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated

Comment: I guess this is not possible with `canActivate` because this is triggered only on navigation, and there is no possibility I know to trigger it manually. Why does it need to be inside `canActivate`? Maybe place it in app component instead?

Comment: Yeah, such a behavior doesn't belong to the routing tasks. Use a service with for example an interval to perform what you need to do every 10 minutes. or if only needed in one component, do it there. For future though if needed elsewhere service is a good choice :)